# c# delegate behaves differently if it is in a class

Tags: c#, delegates

I wanted to have a dictionary of events, but as it is not possible, I am using a dictionary of delegates. Unfortunately the delegate behaves differently if it is inside a class. In case of case 2 I am unable to unsubscribe.
Why does unsubscription work in case of case1 and failes in case of case2?
How can I rewrite my DummyBroadcaster class to make it work?

```
namespace TestApp2
{
    public delegate void StringDelegate(string text);
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dummySubscriber = new MyDummySubscriber();

            #region case1
            StringDelegate stringDelegate = new StringDelegate(dummySubscriber.CallBack);

            Console.WriteLine($"Case 1-> Invoc lenght:{stringDelegate.GetInvocationList().Length}");
            stringDelegate -= dummySubscriber.CallBack;
            if (stringDelegate is null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Case 1-> All subscribed. Success!!");
            }
            #endregion


            #region case2
            DummyBroadcaster dummyBroadcaster = new DummyBroadcaster();
            dummyBroadcaster.Subscribe(dummySubscriber.CallBack);
            dummyBroadcaster.UnSubscribe(dummySubscriber.CallBack);
            dummyBroadcaster.delegatecontainer["dummykey"].Invoke("Oh noooo.");
            #endregion

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    
    class MyDummySubscriber
    {
        public MyDummySubscriber()
        {
        }
        public void CallBack(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Callback called. Msg:{str}");
        }
    }
    public class DummyBroadcaster
    {
        public Dictionary<string, StringDelegate> delegatecontainer=new Dictionary<string, StringDelegate>();
        public DummyBroadcaster()
        {
        }

        public void Subscribe(StringDelegate callback)
        {
            if (delegatecontainer.ContainsKey("dummykey") == false)
            {
                delegatecontainer.Add("dummykey",new StringDelegate(callback));
            }
            else if(delegatecontainer["dummykey"] is null)
            {
                delegatecontainer["dummykey"] = new StringDelegate(callback);
            }
            else
            {
                delegatecontainer["dummykey"] += callback;
            }
        }
        public void UnSubscribe(StringDelegate callback)
        {
            var dummyDelegate = delegatecontainer["dummykey"];

            if (dummyDelegate is not null)
            {
                var invocList = dummyDelegate.GetInvocationList();
                bool contains=dummyDelegate.GetInvocationList().Contains(callback);
                dummyDelegate-=callback;
                if (!contains) { Console.WriteLine($"Case 2-> Error. Not subscribed, so cannot unsubscribe. Current invoc list lenght:{dummyDelegate.GetInvocationList().Length}"); }
            }
            if(dummyDelegate is null)
            {
                DoStuffAfterAllUnsubscribed();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Case 2-> Unsubscribe failed. Invoc list lenght:{dummyDelegate.GetInvocationList().Length}");
            }
        }
        private void DoStuffAfterAllUnsubscribed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"All subscribed. Success!! Invoc list lenght:{delegatecontainer["dummykey"].GetInvocationList().Length}");
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Case 1-> Invoc lenght:1
Case 1-> All subscribed. Success!!
Case 2-> Error. Not subscribed, so cannot unsubscribe. Current invoc list lenght:1
Case 2-> Unsubscribe failed. Invoc list lenght:1
Callback called. Msg:Oh noooo.
done
```

Comment: what behavior do you want? Don't understand your code

Comment: @MinhGiang I would like to be able to unsubscribe in case of Case 2. It looks like "stringDelegate -= dummySubscriber.CallBack;" does not work within the DummyBroadcaster class.

Comment: `dummyDelegate-=callback` -- this line does not mutate `dummyDelegate`, instead it gives you back a new delegate which does not contain `callback`. But you're just throwing this away: you need to store this updated delegate back in the dictionary

Comment: I whish I had asked it few days earlier. :-) Thanks @canton7

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? I rarely, if ever, have seen multicast delegates used outside of events.

Comment: @JonasH The DummyBroadcaster is basically a connector to an exchage. So let's say one of my algorithm wants to recieve data for WTI crude oil, so it subscribes. The broadcaster stores it's callback function in a dictionary and once it recieves a quote update for WTI crude oil, it broadcasts it to the relevant algorithms. If nobody cares about WTI crude oil, then the brodcaster tells the exchage that we don't want this datafeed anymore. Is my approach bad?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do, and we can, if it's possible, re-struct your code, your design pattern

Comment: @MinhGiang just posted it a second before your post. If you have a more efficient way to do it please let me know.

Comment: A broadcaster publish data, some subscribers consum that data, and each subscriber has it own business logic, isn't it?

Comment: @MinhGiang Correct.

Comment: Try to use mediator pattern.  https://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern

Comment: Imagine we are in group chat, so we are subscribers, and when a message come in, all of us can see it, and everyone reacts differently to that message

Comment: I would be very careful using strings in a dictionary like that. Simple spelling errors could cause difficult to detect bugs. I would prefer a regular event since that would let the compiler ensure all the types etc are correct. Possibly with some interfaces and IOC container to get some abstraction between components. If you have more loosely coupled components I would consider some kind of  third-party event-buss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are immutable objects. If you do `Delegate + Delegate` or `Delegate - Delegate`, you don't mutate either of those delegates, instead you get back a new delegate instance.

This means that if you do:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
dict["foo"] = SomeMethod;

var action = dict["foo"];
action -= SomeMethod;
```

You copy the delegate reference stored in the dictionary into the local variable `action`, and then you overwrite the contents of the `action` variable with the result of `action - SomeMethod` (which is `null`), but you never store this back in the dictionary. So while `action` is `null`, `dict["foo"]` still contains the original value you inserted.

You need to store the result of `dict["foo"] - SomeMethod` back into the dictionary, e.g. with:

```
dict["foo"] = action;
```

Or by just doing:

```
dict["foo"] -= action;
```

[See on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHacGR)